# Remove ~20px gap at right side of HTML mail on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, css

Recently I have been working on a contact form for my [portfolio website](http://blieque.comli.com). The form works and I have managed to successfully send HTML mail from the server it's hosted on to my email address. Like most of my emails, these will be primarily read on my iPod Touch so the theme I based the mail template on is engineered for a screen `320px` by `480px`.

Even though the mail container element is set to `width:100%` and the same on all inner elements, there is a ~20px gap at the right side of the screen, as if that's the edge of the document:

[image]

Here is the script and style-sheet for reference:

PHP (snippet), `request_form.php`:

```
...
$email_subject = "Graphic Request - ".clean_string($first_name);

$email_message .= '<html><head><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://blieque.comli.com/mail-styles.css" type="text/css"></head><body><table id="all" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">';
$email_message .= '<tr><td id="head"><h1>New Request</h1></td></tr>';
$email_message .= '<tr><td class="info"><span id="param">Name:</span> '.clean_string($first_name).'</td></tr>';
$email_message .= '<tr><td class="info sub"><span id="param">Email Address:</span> '.clean_string($email_from).'</td></tr>';
$email_message .= '<tr><td class="info sub"><span id="param">Service:</span> '.clean_string($service).'</td></tr>';
$email_message .= '<tr><td class="info sub jstfy"><span id="param">Details:</span> '.clean_string($request).'</td></tr>';
$email_message .= '<tr><td id="foot"></td></tr></table></body></html>';
...
```

CSS, `mail-styles.css`:

```
body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #242424 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    }
#all {
    width: 110%;
    }
#head {
    background: #1393A1;
    color: #61BDC7;
    border-bottom: solid 0.5em #61BDC7;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
    height: 20px;
    }
td.sub {
    border-top: solid 0.25em #1393a1;
    }
td.info {
    padding: 0.35em 0.5em;
    font-size: 12pt;
    }
td.jstfy {
    text-align: justify;
    }
span#param {
    color: #1393a1;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
td[class=info] {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    }
#foot {
    background: #1393a1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    color: transparent;
    border-top: solid 0.5em #61BDC7;
    }
#line {
    background: #1393a1;
    width: 94%;
    height: 0.25em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }
```

The email also doesn't work well with online email viewers as they tend to have their own overriding style-sheets for common tags like `<h1>`. I hope the solution is something obvious.

Comment: FOr me it was an issue with padding/cellpadding when you have 100% width table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding min-width: 100% to the `<body>` element to deal with the gap.

And as the others suggested, moving your styles inline should deal with the rest of your problems.

Comment: All good now. :) A `min-width: 100%` property on both the `body` and `html` tags sorted it out.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

When I used `min-width` instead of `width`, the content got too wide. I also have these viewport settings in my header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mark the correct answer as accepted. Thanks for the information though. I don't remember ever using the `meta` tags; this was a while ago. I use them a lot now. :)

Comment: Worked for me, although I used inline style.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the bit about the external css file. I would suggest not using that, move everything in there into a `<style type="text/css">` element in the `<head>` of the email.

Comment: Ok, two said to do so so I'll try it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML emails don't handle external stylesheets very well so this may be your problem.

You should only use inline styles on HTML emails as a general rule of thumb.

Here's a good guide on HTML emails:
http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-to-code-html-emails

Comment: I keep it external so it's easier to manage and everything else on the style-sheet works fine. I'll try later if nothing else works.

Comment: I'd recommend NOT putting your css into a style tag. Put it INLINE only. Do some Googling and you'll see that this is the recommended pratice. Basically write your html email code like it's 1996. use FONT tags etc. Keep your CSS to a bare minimum as lots of email clients will ignore it.

Comment: I understand but I also don't see why. Everything else works. Previously I was using other percentages and they were working great. I can't understand why this gap exists. I'm pretty sure it's an iOS problem, but it doesn't appear on any other emails.

Comment: Is it maybe somtheing to do with that width:110% you have set on the table?

Comment: I set that in the hope it would extend over the white gap. `100%` renders exactly the same.

Comment: Went back to basics with this. Might find something here that helps. http://jsfiddle.net/EC7f9/1/

Comment: I'll try both a `width` attribute on the table and a `min-width` property via CSS.

Comment: Aha! Adding a `min-width` of 100% to the `<html>` and `<body>` works! There is unfortunately another gap, now at the bottom of the page.. Maybe a `min-height` too will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16202/discussion-between-blieque-and-billy-moat)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `body` has padding by default on most browsers. add:

```
body{
    padding:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've dealt with this issue numerous times.  Every time it occurs I always realize that it's happening because I'm using cellpadding incorrectly on one of my tables.

For example, I got caught up for a bit today because near the bottom of one of the emails I was working on there is a table with a press banner that stretches horizontally across the bottom like this:

```
<center><!-- Press Banner -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <a role="link" href="#" target="_blank" title="#">
                <span class="press">
                    <img class="desktop" src="#" border="0" style="display:block;">
                </span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

That image is 600 pixels wide and is switched for a 320 pixel wide background image for the mobile layout.  I needed to add some vertical spacing between that block and the others so I chose to add cellpadding="15" to do so, without realizing that 15 pixels would also stretch out horizontally.  But on the iOS device this is extra space only renders on the right side, not the left, so its not obvious what the problem is.

To fix it, I removed the cellpadding and used table spacers instead on the top and bottom.

```
<tr>
    <td><table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0"><tr><td height="4"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td>
</tr>
```

There are many other reasons that this issue could occur as other people have already mentioned, but just adding this potential cause for anyone else who may be overlooking the same error that I made.

---

Additionally as a rule of thumb, you should never import CSS in an HTML email, you should inline as much style as possible and use depreciated CSS2 tags and oldschool HTML styling elements whenever possible to achieve the highest level of cross device, client compability.  I recently uploaded a project to [github(link)](https://github.com/dcondrey/html-email) which is the html email template I've created while building emails for some time.  It's pretty much the most compatible template you'll find anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! As for compatibility, I appreciate your effort and would use it in a production environment, but this particular email was only designed to be sent to me and read on my iPod Touch. This was also a long time ago, and I'd never use tables if I was to create the template again.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it was quite some time ago.  Kinda posted it just as much for myself as anything.  I'm often searching S.O. old posts to find answers to issues so next time when I have this problem I'll see my post and remember. lol